# Set v-switch to be on, with value: 'false' (invert value with v-model)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a `v-switch` that I'd like to be "on/true" so that the switch is to the right, but still have the v-model value to be "false", and then when the switch is "off/false" have the v-model value to be "true", essentially inverting the values.

I'm struggling to find this an option or how to do this. I'm using Vuetify 1.5.15:

```html
<v-switch color="success" prepend-icon="notifications_off" v-model="url.muteNotifications" @click.capture.prevent.stop="togglePolling(url, urlNo)"></v-switch>
```

Comment: how about `v-model="!url.muteNotifications"` then toggle that?

Comment: This works, until I click the switch, I then get two errors: `Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: false` and `TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'muteNotifications' in false
    at Proxy.set (commons.app.js:14811)`. Also,  `muteNotifications` is coming from an object,

Comment: so use a computed:
`
v-model="someProperty"
...
 someProperty(){
    return !url.muteNotifications
}
`

Comment: I'm not sure whether it would work as I have an array of objects, each object contains a muteNotification key, so having one in the data wouldn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### its not value - its [input-value](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/f55071368fe0bc99d6bda8538ccfa83875c8df63/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/selectable/index.ts#L20)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      t:false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change(){
      console.log("change");
      this.t=!this.t;
    }
  },
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<v-app>
  <v-content>
    <v-switch :input-value="!t" @change="change">Hello world</v-switch>
  </v-content>
</v-app>
</div>
```

## but you can also define `false` as truish

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      t:false
    }
  },
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<v-app>
  <v-content>
    <v-switch v-model="t" :false-value="true" :true-value="false">Hello world</v-switch>
  </v-content>
</v-app>
</div>
```

#### but this breaks [colors](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/f55071368fe0bc99d6bda8538ccfa83875c8df63/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/selectable/index.ts#L38) - [imo a bug](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8629)

Answer (score 1):

Decompose `model` on `value` and `change` and reverse the algorithm, like this:

```
<v-switch :value="!mute" @change="(v) => mute = !v" :label="`Switch mute: ${mute.toString()}`"></v-switch>
```

**v-model & reversed**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-switch v-model="mute" :label="`Switch mute: ${mute.toString()}`"></v-switch>
      <v-switch :value="!mute" @change="(v) => mute = !v" :label="`Switch mute reversed: ${mute.toString()}`"></v-switch>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      mute: true
    }
  } 
})
</script>
```

**For an Array**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <div v-for="(sound, index) in sounds" :key="index">
      <v-switch v-model="sound.mute" :label="`Switch mute of ${sound.name}: ${sound.mute.toString()}`"></v-switch>
      <v-switch :value="!sound.mute" @change="(v) => sound.mute = !v" :label="`Switch mute of ${sound.name} reversed: ${sound.mute.toString()}`"></v-switch>
      </div>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      sounds: [{name:'first', mute: true}, {name:'second', mute: true}]
    }
  } 
})
```

Live example: https://codepen.io/andriykuba/pen/abomQYe

Comment: I'm not sure whether it would work as I have an array of objects, each object contains a muteNotification key, so having one in the data wouldn't work.

Comment: This is great, this works, but when I reload the page, the switch reverts to the original value. (I'm storing my array of objects in vuex, in Nuxt JS, the value is coming back correctly, but the switch doesn't update to that value)

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify default value is true/false

```
 <v-switch
  v-model="sales.final_info.reverse_charge"
 ></v-switch>
```

Vuetify custom switch value set by false-value and true-value attribute

```
 <v-switch         
 false-value="NO"
 true-value="YES"
 v-model="sales.final_info.reverse_charge">
</v-switch>
```